# Colored cells in Squirrel SQL client

Tags: squirrel-sql

I use Squirrel SQL client to query my DB2 database. When I query one of the tables, I see some of the cells background are shown colored (teal). I am not sure why those cells can be shown in a teal color while other cells’ background are still in white. I did some research online and found multiple scenarios where the cells could be colored.

1. If the cells have multi-line texts.
2. If the cells have reached the maximum number of allowed characters.
3. If the cells are set as read-only.

Based on the above, I checked my table structure. All the colored cells have multi-line texts. None of them have reached the maximum allowed limit in number of characters. I right clicked in a colored cell and I am able to make it editable. Only match I could find is, all the colored cells have multi-line texts. Is there any other reasons that could cause the cells to be shown in a different color?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some more research in my table structure and got answer.

> Squirrel shows colored cells only when they have multi-line texts in them.